# Line selector on v-datatables (Vuetify)

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, v-data-table

Can you help me?

I want to have the same result in vuejs3 , I use v-datatable and my problem is that I don’t know how to select a line with the v-datatable of Vuejs3

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to color it by position (i.e. first two rows should always be green, no matter the sorting), you can use CSS:

```css
    .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n+2) td{
      background: #e1eed7;
    }
    .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+4) td{
      background: #fff1c7;
    }
    .v-table > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+6) td{
      background: #fce3d4;
    }
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    const headers = [{key: 'id', title: 'ID'},{key: 'name', title: 'Name'}]
    const items = ref(Array.from({length:8}, (_,i) => ({
          id: 1 + i, 
          name: `Item ${1 + i}`
        })))
   
    return {
      headers,
      items,
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.v-data-table.colortable .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr th{
  background: #d7d7d7;
}
.v-table.colortable > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(-n+2) td{
  background: #e1eed7;
}
.v-table.colortable > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+4) td{
  background: #fff1c7;
}
.v-table.colortable > .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+6) td{
  background: #fce3d4;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.13/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.13/dist/vuetify-labs.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-data-table
        class="colortable"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        item-title="name"
        item-value="id"
      ></v-data-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.13/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.13/dist/vuetify-labs.js"></script>
```

In Vuetify 2, you could set a row class through the associated item, but this is not supported by the current version of VDataTable (Vuetify 3.1.13).

Comment: No, that's not what I want, I want to select a line in <tr> and the colorers but, I don't know what is the selector of the line <tr> of the dataTables of the viewjs3

Thank you for answering

Comment: Oh, so you want the CSS selectors for tr in dataTables? Check the updated answer